# How to delete lines in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I am looking to provide a additional option to my drawing application by giving the user the ability to delete lines that he has already draw on the `JPanel`.

The above code is about drawing lines on the `JPanel`

Can anyone provide me a method to delete a specific line?

Per example a method that provides the user the ability to click on a button in the window, then to select a specific line and delete.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawLine extends JPanel {

    private MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler();
    private Point p1 = new Point(0, 0);
    private Point p2 = new Point(0, 0);
    private boolean drawing;

    //Store lines in an arraylist
    private ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    public DrawLine() {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 600));
        this.addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //Grid start
        g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
        int sideLength = 20;
        int nRowCount = getHeight() / sideLength;
        int currentX = sideLength;
        for (int i = 0; i < nRowCount; i++) {
            g.drawLine(0, currentX, getWidth(), currentX);
            currentX = currentX + sideLength;
        }

        int nColumnCount = getWidth() / sideLength;
        int currentY = sideLength;
        for (int i = 0; i < nColumnCount; i++) {
            g.drawLine(currentY, 0, currentY, getHeight());
            currentY = currentY + sideLength;
        }
        //Grid end

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(8,
            BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL));
        g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);

        //draw all previous lines
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) { 
            g.drawLine(lines.get(i).p1.x, lines.get(i).p1.y, lines.get(i).p2.x, lines.get(i).p2.y);
        }
    }

    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            drawing = true;
            p1 = e.getPoint();
            p2 = p1;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            drawing = false;
            p2 = e.getPoint();
            repaint();
            lines.add(new Line(p1, p2));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (drawing) {
                p2 = e.getPoint();
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("LinePanel");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DrawLine().display();
            }
        });
    }

    public class Line {
        Point p1;
        Point p2;

        public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
            this.p1 = p1;
            this.p2 = p2;
        }
    }
}
```

Delete a line means delete the line coordinates from the `ArrayList`, but my problem is how to handle a new mouse action when clicking a delete button and how to turn off the old mouse action (the one that let the user to draw lines)

Comment: drawLine is like using some brush on a frame, there's no delete (only some paint over maybe)

Comment: @RC. : Delete a line means delete the line coordinates from the ArrayList, but my problem is how to handle a new mouse action when clicking a delete button and how to turn off the old mouse action (the one that let the user to draw lines)

Comment: `MouseEvent`s are like raindrops, they won't fall further then the component that is monitoring for them (like an umbrella), so, if you have a `JButton` for example, it will prevent `MouseEvent`s from falling through to it's parent container. You could have a flag which can be turned on and off, so you would click the remove button (probably a `JToggleButton`), set the flag and then select the line you want to remove, the flag which change the way you `MouseListener` handled events

Comment: @MadProgrammer : Thanks, but can you give me a full example as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first for found the clicked line   `Line2D.Double(point1, point2).ptSegDist()` method can be used. This method returning the distance between the line and the given point. If distance is smaller than 4 (because of your stroke width is 8) it means user clicked that line. That was the hardest part.

After that, I added a boolean member to `Line` class to keep the "clicked" information. And at last, in delete action I loop in `lines` list and remove the selected ones.

Note that, I am using `isControlDown()` for determine if user want to select a line or want to draw another line. Because somehow I had to decide what is the desired operation.

```
public class DrawLine extends JPanel {

    private static final int LINE_WIDTH = 8;

    private MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler();
    private Point p1 = null;
    private Point p2 = null;
    private boolean drawing;

    private Point draggingPoint = null;

    // Store lines in an arraylist
    private ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    public DrawLine() {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        this.addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Grid start
        g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
        int sideLength = 20;
        int nRowCount = getHeight() / sideLength;
        int currentX = sideLength;
        for (int i = 0; i < nRowCount; i++) {
            g.drawLine(0, currentX, getWidth(), currentX);
            currentX = currentX + sideLength;
        }

        int nColumnCount = getWidth() / sideLength;
        int currentY = sideLength;
        for (int i = 0; i < nColumnCount; i++) {
            g.drawLine(currentY, 0, currentY, getHeight());
            currentY = currentY + sideLength;
        }
        // Grid end

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(LINE_WIDTH, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL));

        if (p1 != null && p2 != null) {
            g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
        }

        // draw all previous lines
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            Line line = lines.get(i);
            if (line.isSelected) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.red);
            } else {
                g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
            }
            g.drawLine(lines.get(i).p1.x, lines.get(i).p1.y, lines.get(i).p2.x, lines.get(i).p2.y);
        }
    }

    private void deSelectAll() {
        for (Line line : lines) {
            line.isSelected = false;
        }
    }

    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (!e.isControlDown()) {
                drawing = true;
                p1 = e.getPoint();
                p2 = p1;
                repaint();
            } else {
                for (Line line : lines) {
                    line.isSelected = false;
                    if (isInside(line, e.getPoint())) {
                        line.isSelected = true;
                    }
                }

                draggingPoint = e.getPoint();

                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (!e.isControlDown()) {
                drawing = false;
                p2 = e.getPoint();
                repaint();
                deSelectAll();
                lines.add(new Line(p1, p2));

                p1 = null;
                p2 = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (!e.isControlDown()) {
                if (drawing) {
                    p2 = e.getPoint();
                    repaint();
                }
            } else if (draggingPoint != null) {

                int XDiff = e.getPoint().x - draggingPoint.x;
                int YDiff = e.getPoint().y - draggingPoint.y;

                draggingPoint = e.getPoint();

                for (Line line : lines) {
                    if (line.isSelected) {
                        line.p1.x = line.p1.x + XDiff;
                        line.p1.y = line.p1.y + YDiff;
                        line.p2.x = line.p2.x + XDiff;
                        line.p2.y = line.p2.y + YDiff;
                    }
                }

                repaint();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns true if the given point is inside the given line.
         */
        private boolean isInside(Line line, Point p) {
            return new Line2D.Double(line.p1, line.p2).ptSegDist(p) < (LINE_WIDTH / 2);
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("LinePanel");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);

        f.add(new JButton(new DeleteLineAction()), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class DeleteLineAction extends AbstractAction {

        public DeleteLineAction() {
            super("Delete");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Iterator<Line> iterator = lines.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Line line = iterator.next();

                if (line.isSelected) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }

            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DrawLine().display();
            }
        });
    }

    class Line {
        Point p1;
        Point p2;

        boolean isSelected;

        public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
            this.p1 = p1;
            this.p2 = p2;

            isSelected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seems not working fine, and it is better that the user have the ability to select the line that he wish to delete and than click on the delete button.

Comment: Did you try with ctrl button? If you clicked a line when control button is pressed, clicked line's color will be red. Then after pressing the delete button red line will be deleted. And I think you have to define two mode; select mode and draw mode. In my case pressing control button activate the select mode, you can change it anything else.

Comment: And I think there no way to solve you issue without defining modes. Because if user clicked a line maybe he is wanting to draw a new line or maybe select the clicked line. Somehow you must  decide what the user want to do.

Comment: Ok it is working using ctrl button, so I am accepting the answer now, one more thing, I have implemented a method using c# for draging the line and drop it in another place (let the user to change any line coordinates by selecting it and then move it to another place), it is possible here in java? or it is a complex issue? thanks

Comment: There was a little bug in my code, I fixed it, please use updated one. And I will look for a way to dragging lines, because of we are knowing the selected line, we can drag it I think.

Comment: It is perfect now.
Yes please because the dragging line option is important to my application, thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108698/discussion-between-jad-chahine-and-resit-donuk).

Answer (score 1):

What you would most likely have to do is have some kind of line manager that stores the lines that you want drawn in a list. Any time you add or remove a line, the line manager would tell the frame to redraw itself.

In order to check if a user has clicked on the line for the selection is to implement Circle to Line collision, using the mouse position for the circle, and a radius of your choice (1px would be fine if you wanted it exactly where the mouse was clicked). This link shows the math behind such a collision:
http://devmag.org.za/2009/04/17/basic-collision-detection-in-2d-part-2/

An easier solution if you aren't friends with math is to iterate through the lines of the line manager, highlighting the one that the user is currently on in a different colour, rather than having them click to select the line.

Answer (score 0):

You will want some other gesture to indicate line removal.  Perhaps add a check for a RMB (Right mouse button) click in your `MouseHandler`, which will then try to find a `Line` that the click corresponds to.  Then remove the `Line` from the `ArrayList`, and call `repaint()`.  When `paint` is called, there will be one fewer `Line`s to paint.